# How to unlink (delete) an image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

I try to `unlink` an image in CodeIgniter, but the `unlink` function shows:

> notice Undefined index: userfile

Here is my code

```
<?php
    function get_from_post(){
        $data['logo_name']  = $this->input->post('logo_name',TRUE);
        $data['logo_thumb'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        return $data;
    }

    function deleteconf($data){
        $data= $this->get_from_post();
        $update_id=$this->uri->segment(3);

        @unlink(base_url.'image/logo_thumb'.$logo_thumb);

        $query= $this->_delete($update_id);     
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$logo_thumb` come from? I can't see where you've assigned the value.

Comment: its come from post(form value)

Comment: And what about `base_url`? Is that the CodeIgniter `base_url()`?

Answer (score 4):

> the unlink function shows notice Undefined index: `userfile`

### The upload form, using multipart/form-data

Make sure you've use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute/value for your upload form.

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype):

> **enctype**
> `multipart/form-data`: Use this value if you are using an `<input>`
> element with the type attribute set to "file".

If you're going to use CodeIgniter [form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html), you could use `form_open_multipart()` function:

> This function is absolutely identical to the `form_open()` tag above
> except that it adds a multipart attribute, which is necessary if you
> would like to use the form to upload files with.

### Deleting files, File path vs URL address

PHP [`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/unlink) function accepts the **Path** of the file as the first argument. Not the **URL Address**.

The [`base_url()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L64-L68) helper function [returns the URL address](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Config.php#L282) of the site, [which you've set](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/application/config/config.php#L17) in the `config.php` file.

You'll have to use the path of the file on your server, as follows:

```php
unlink('/path/to/image/image_name.jpg'); // This is an absolute path to the file
```

You could use an **Absolute** or **Relative** path, but note that the *relative path* **is relative to** the `index.php` file. i.e. If the `image/` folder is placed beside `index.php` file, you should use `image/image_name.jpg` as the file path:

```php
unlink('image/image_name.jpg'); // This is a relative path to the file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload a photo for user profile and also
 at the time the old user photo should be deleted by 
using unlink method in codeignitor

```
$query = $this->db->where('profile_id',$profile_id)->get('users')->row();
$result = $query->photo;
$result = http://localhost/abc/user_photo/FE12563.jpg

if ($result) {
        $dd = substr($result, strlen(base_url()));
        unlink($dd);
        return  $this->db->set('photo',$photo)->where('profile_id',$profile_id)->update('users');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the file name in the database and your file is abc.jpg. Then to unlink that in Code Igniter just do -

```
$file = "abc.jpg";
$prev_file_path = "./assets/uploads/files/".$file;
if(file_exists($prev_file_path ))
    unlink($prev_file_path );
```

My file upload path is "public_html/assets/uploads/files/". I am writing the above code in my controller which is "public_html/application/controllers/MyController.php". So the path will be same which I used in my CI file upload section. i.e.

```
...
$config['upload_path']   = './assets/uploads/files';
...
```

So we used relative path in both the upload and unlink section. So if the upload works perfectly then this will also work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_from_post(){
      $filename = $_POST['logo_name'];
      $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/projectname/uploads/'.$filename ;
      if(is_file($path)){
        unlink($path);
        echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
      } else {
        echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
      }
  }
```

Comment: i try ed its shows notice Undefined index: file_exits

Answer (score 0):

First check your file input name. Is it "userfile" or not?
if not then add it and then run it once again.

Comment: input name is userfile

Comment: print the $_FILES array and check whether it contains "userfile" or not

Comment: i try to print the $_FILES its shows again undefined index :userfile

Comment: try this print_r($_FILES);

Comment: output produce  an empty array: Array()

Comment: that means there is no file uploaded by user. In such case you can check whether the $_FILES is empty or not and if its empty then assign a default thumb

Answer (score 0):

base_url() function returns url of you project but here you have to use directory path of file which you want to delete.

```
$path = BASEPATH.'/assets/upload/employees/contracts/'; 
$get_file = $path.$con_id.'.jpg'; 
 if(file_exists($get_file)){ 
 unlink($get_file); 
 }
```

---

instead of `unlink(base_url("/assets/upload/employees/contracts/'.$con_id."));`

Answer (score 0):

**First unlink function work only with path (without url), so please remove base_url() function.**

Then in your first function **$_FILES** array doesn't contain **userfile** index, that's why getting error.

***NOTE:- Before using unlink i would like to use also file_exists() function, first it will check if file is exist on same path then use unlink function (for error handling).***

Like that -

```
<?php 
if(file_exists(filePath))
{
 unlink(filePath);
}

?>
```

Please fix both issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, you need to get first the path of directory from    where you have uploaded your image.
Exemple:

```php
//this is your url
$mainPath='https://google.com/uploads/image/16.jpeg';
$uploadedDirectory=str_replace("https://google.com/","./", $mainPath);
//now you get path like this ./uploads/image/16.jpeg
if(unlink($uploadedDirectory)) {
    $this->db->where('prodId',$id);
    $this->db->delete('products');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->load->helper("file");
```

just add above line before unlink

```
unlink($path);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please use this code to remove image on folder.

unlink(realpath('uploads/' . $_image));

"uploads" : Image exist in uploads folder.
"$_image" : Image file name

PHP functions:
1 : unlink()
2 : realpath()

The above code successfully working on my site to delete image on folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
# CodeIgniter 3
# These methods will give you the document root path in CodeIgniter 3. You can use this path to construct URLs, file paths, or for any other purposes that require the document root.
    
         public function delete()
         {
            $id = $this->input->get('id');
    
    
            if(!empty($id))
            {
                $this->db->select("pdf_link");
                $this->db->from("ad_study");
                $this->db->where("st_id",$id);
    
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $data = $query->row_object();
    
                // $file = base_url('uploads/'.$data->pdf_link);
                $file = FCPATH.'/uploads/'.$data->pdf_link;
    
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    if (unlink($file)) {
                        echo "File deleted successfully.";
                    } else {
                        echo "Unable to delete the file.";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "File does not exist.";
                }
    
                // die;
                $this->db->where('st_id',$id);
                $this->db->delete("ad_study");
    
                $this->session->set_flashdata('db_success','Success - Data Delete Successfully ');
                redirect('admin/material');
            }
         }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
unlink(base_url().'/image/logo_thumb'.$logo_thumb);
```

Note: You didn't assign / declare `$logo_thumb` in your `deleteconf()`.

Please check your code.

Comment: i try ed  its shows notice Undefined index: userfile

Comment: I think you did not post full code. userfile variable doesn't exist in your code. Post full code clearly. Otherwise your question will be flagged as unclear.