# How to delete all image from folder and i saved all images file name into table in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to delete all images from a folder and my saved all images file name into a table. When I click to delete one row, I want to delete all images related to this file name in a row deleted... I tried unlink but not working, my query was only deleted table row values only, not folder path image... Can anyone tell me how doing it...

In codeigniter and mysql...

Thanks
Tamilselvan V

Comment: `unlink` in php see this...! and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642525/how-to-unlink-delete-an-image-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this code inside a controller.

```
 <?php
            $files = glob("folder_path/*");
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                unlink($file);
            }
  ?>
```

if unlink doesn't works then go to the specific folder and check the read/write permissions.